# AsyncTask doInBackground(); executing multiple methods one by one

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having trouble with `AsyncTask` running multiple methods in `doInBackground`. this is my `AsyncTask` code:

```
 public class FETCHDATA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pdialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        pdialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try{

        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
        method4();
        method5();
        method6();
        method7();

       }catch (Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }


   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (pdialog.isShowing()){
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Instead running and waiting the first method is done, the `doInBackground` proceeds to the next method. and the `ProgressDialog` dismiss by one second.

**Note**
Every Method will get data from our `API` and save it on my `SQLiteDatabase` .

**QUESTION**
How can i execute my methods when the first method has finished getting and saving data before moving to the second methods.

Comment: i think you need to use rx java, where you can call multiple network calls one by one !

Comment: You can make use of [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) instead of using AsyncTasks.

Comment: `Instead running and waiting the first method is done, the doInBackground proceeds to the next method.` Nonsense. They are called one after another.  Are there any things you did not tell us but should have done?

Comment: Further you did not post code for one of those 'methods' nor did you tell what those 'methods' do. So what do you expect from us?

Comment: Please check the  **Note**

Answer (score 0):

You can put a counter with a switch case statment in the `doInBackground` in wich you choose the methode to execute and then in the `onPostExecute` call `new FETCHDATA().execute()` recursively

**EDIT :** working code ( i forgot `break;` after `case;`)

```
int counter = 1; // global

class Fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            switch (counter) {
                case 1:
                    method1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    method2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    method3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    method4();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    method5();
                    break;
                default:
                    cancel(true);
                    counter = 1;
                    break;
            }


        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        counter+=1;
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: "+counter);
        // cancel(true);
        new Fetchdata().execute();
    }
}

void method1(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "methode1: coucou");
}

void method2(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "methode2: ");
}

void method3(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "methode3: ");
}

void method4(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "methode4: ");
}

void method5(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "methode5: ");
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170291/discussion-between-e-abdel-and-mike-neries-gorospe).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to create multiples AsyncTask and whenever the first method finish, communicate it with returning a boolean instead of void instance here ---> extends AsyncTask.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. i used `AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>` and return  `onBackground()` true. it makes the progress dialog disappear

Answer (score 0):

This is weird.

I assume that your `methodX()` are asynchronous call?

In that case, you can use `Thread.join()` or `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: my methods are `public void method1()`

Answer (score 0):

You are violating usage of async task. Async task is designed for doing short async operations and update the UI easily before, during and after, It is not for doing 7 network & Sqlite operations at once.

You can read more here, : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

So you need to implement some kind of job for yourself to execute these operations at once or use some popular libraries like Retrofit.

If you insist to use async task, since an async task need to be executed from UI thread, you need to create new async task an execute it from onPostExecute every time when it is done and you of course need to pass a param(a counter or something) to doInBackground to know which method should be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your all methods or some methods already runs on a separate thread . So whenever you call a method which already runs on separate thread `doInBackground()` i.e current thread will not wait for it and continue the execution.

Apart from that The way you put `try-catch` is not a proper way to do it . Also if you want to call  several threads one after another you should go with `ThreadPoolExecuter`.

If you are not using a Network library To make API calls you can use [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: I'm getting the data to API using `FastAndroidNetworking`